# Asking for feedback rather than a specific question

Tags: discussion

I'm developing a new cyberpunk game based on the FATE system. What I have seen here is that there are a lot of people who could give feedback and constructive criticism to my game in development. However, I do not have a specific question about it(for now).

I know that game design questions are on topic but how about just asking for general feedback? I feel like it would not fit the Q&A format well, but I'd definitely want to ask for feedback in this great community.

How do you think I should seek feedback on my new game? Is rpg.se the right place for it? Should I maybe use the chat? Should I go to another site?

#### Update

I opened a [chatroom for the purpose](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2152/edgerunner-rpg-feedback), feel free to drop by and leave your feedback.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Definitely bring it to chat!  We love to discuss things like this, and I suspect that we can help you identify particular issues that will make good questions.

The primary site just isn't designed to handle general feedback on a topic (even a specific game idea).

Comment: and, what he said ;)

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestions on how to promote a chat room for this purpose on the main site?

Comment: @edgerunner We can create you a room for the purpose (actually you can too), if people come talk about it, it'll automatically show up in the chat side bar like you see `The Game Table` and `The Back Room` now.

Comment: My preference would be to keep it in the main room until folks tell you to get your own place.  I like to listen in on most things, but end up not visiting other rooms much.

Comment: Chatroom is up, chime in :)

Answer (score 5):

Take it to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/the-game-table)!

It'll work out much better as I bet it would benefit from the immediate feedback and discussion cycle.  Much better than a 50 comment thread on the site would anyways.

Comment: Bring friends!  There's been a spur of chatroom activity the last few weeks.